# Fast double key pressed on Jbutton leads results in same operation twice

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

1> I have a **JButton** in **Jframe**.

2> The click of **JButton** opens new **instance** of another **JFrame**.

The problem is when a Key is pressed very fast on the above **Jbutton** .Two instances of the same **JFrame** opens up.

I have to open these frames. I knows there are other options also not using the Jframes as I read.

I managed to solve this problem for Doulbl click of Mouce by **setMultiClickThreshHold('time in miliseconds')**. But it worked **only for mouse**.

Tried some other stuffs which I got in google, But none worked.
Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For full control of how often/quickly again an Action is triggered, implement it to disable itself in its actionPerformed. Something like:

```
singlePerform = new AbstractAction("DoSomthing") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setEnabled(false);
        doSomething();
    }
};
JButton button = new JButton(singlePerform);
```

When it's safe for doSomething to be triggered again, simply re-enable the Action:

```
singlePerform.setEnabled(true);
```